# Differentiability at zero of this function

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis, derivatives

$$f(x) = |x| \sin(x)$$

With the definition I have to check if the second derivative at zero is defined.

So for the second derivative I have

$$f''(0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(0+h) - 2f(0) + f(0-h)}{h^2}$$

That is

$$f''(0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{|h|\sin(h) + |-h|\sin(-h)}{h^2}$$

Now collecting $\sin(h)$ I recognize the notable limit $\sin(h)/h$ hence what remains is

$$f''(0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{|h| - |-h|}{h}$$

But now I got stuck because when $h \to 0^+$ we have $|h| = h$ and $|-h| = -(-h) = h$ hence

$$\lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{|h| - |-h|}{h} = 0$$

But I get the same at $0^-$ because here $|h| = -h$ and $|-h| = -h$ hence the limit is still zero.

Yet the notes tell me the answer is undefined because the two limits are different. I don't get how...

Comment: What is the definition of $f''(x)$, to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not compute the derivative explicitly first? Observe that if $x>0$, then $f(x)=x\sin x$, so $f'(x)=\sin x+x\cos x$, and if $x<0$, then $f(x)=-x\sin x$, so $f'(x)=-(\sin x+x\cos x)$. Finally

$$\left\lvert\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}\right\rvert=\left\lvert\frac{\lvert h\rvert\sin h}{h}\right\rvert=\lvert\sin h\rvert\to0$$

as $h\to0$, so $f'(0)=0$. Consequently

$$f'(x)=\begin{cases}
\sin x+x\cos x,&x\geq0,\\
-(\sin x+x\cos x),&x<0.
\end{cases}$$

But now the problem is easy, as

$$\lim_{h\downarrow0}\frac{f'(h)-f'(0)}{h}=\lim_{h\downarrow0}\frac{\sin h+h\cos h}{h}=\lim_{h\downarrow0}\frac{\sin h}{h}+\lim_{h\downarrow0}\cos h=2,$$

but

$$\lim_{h\uparrow0}\frac{f'(h)-f'(0)}{h}=-\lim_{h\uparrow0}\frac{\sin h+h\cos h}{h}=-2,$$

and consequently $f'$ is not differentiable at $0$, i.e. $f$ is not twice differentiable at $0$.

---

As for where your solution goes wrong, the limit you're considering is only equal to the second derivative *if it exists*, but it may still exist without the second derivative doing so. Compare it to the symmetric derivative of a function, which is

$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x-h)}{2h},$$

which is equal to the derivative of $f$ at $x$ *if the derivative exists*.  It may still exist without the derivative doing so though. An example is $f(x)=\lvert x\rvert$. It has symmetric derivative equal to $0$ at $0$, but it's clearly not differentiable there. What's going on with your solution is analogous but for the second derivative.

Comment: The problem asks for using the definition ONLY

Comment: @Numb3rs The definition of the second derivative *is* the derivative of the first derivative, *not* the limit you have though

Comment: Ok! But then how can I use the definition without knowing what $f'(x+h)$ and $f'(x)$ is? (Then $x = 0$)

Comment: @Numb3rs why do you want to do it without them though? There's nothing wrong with finding them first, and imo it's the most natural thing to do here to be able to use the definition of the second derivative

Comment: I know it's easy to find $f'(x)$ in the algebraic way, but this I must avoid. I only have to use the definition, that is the limit of the ratio. So I don't know how to show $f''(0)$ does not exist, using only limits without knowing explicitely what $f'(h)$ is (because anyway $f'(0) = 0$ this I know)

Comment: @Numb3rs I mean finding $f'$ using the definition of the derivative shouldn't be that hard either, so I don't see why not

Comment: Ohh, Now I got what you meant!! Sorry, and thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The initial limit statement is incorrect.
First, [Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem) provides if $f$ is twice differentiable at some $x\in\mathbb{R}$:
$$ f(x+h) = f(x) + hf'(x) + \frac {h^2} 2 f''(x) + o(h^2),$$
which yields
$$ \frac {f(x+h) - f(x)} h = f'(x) + \frac h 2 f''(x) + o(h)$$
and
$$ \frac {f(x-h) - f(x)} {-h} = f'(x) + \frac {-h} 2 f''(x) + o(h),$$
whence we deduce by summing:
$$ \frac {f(x+h)-f(x-h)} h = h f''(x) + o(h).$$
The correct limit statement is therefore (if the limit existed):
\begin{align*}
f''(0) &= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac {f(0+h) - f(0-h)}{h^2} \\
&= \frac {|h|\sin(h) - |-h|\sin(-h)} {h^2} \\
&= \frac {|h|} h \times 2\frac {\sin(h)} h, 
\end{align*}
and you have your contradiction using that $\sin(h)/h \to 1$.